# Are Authorized NT Users stored in a table in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-authentication

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.
While generating custom reports, I need to provide specific parameters based on the logged in user. That's why my app requires a table for users with their ids, so that I can join whatever else I want with them.
The problem starts when I inspect the results of querying Master..SysUsers. My NT user is not listed, however in the SysLogins table, my NT user account is listed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft said something [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179871.aspx)

They suggested that we rather use sys.database_principals, sys.sql_logins than SysUser, SysLogins.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but it seemed the result set is the same. There is only one Windows User (which seems to be a reporting service/server) appearing in the query instead of all the supposedly authorized users.

Comment: Does the account you using for data access (from program) have full privilege? Seem no problem as this article wrote :http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1252. In that, they use `master.sys.server_principals`. Good luck!